# Django development server restarts when changing template (HTML) files

Tags: django, development-environment

I started a new project in Django 3.2. Unlike what I am used to, on my development machine the runserver restarts automatically when I change template files (HTML files). I am not used to this happening - normally these would always be loaded from disk and changes did not require a restart. A restart is fast but not instantaneous and I rather have the old behavior. I checked the [changelog](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/releases/3.2/) and the [runserver](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/django-admin/#runserver) documentation but I am not sure if this really is a recent change, or a setting, or if I am overlooking something.

Anyone any idea? Below the output of the server in my docker container where you can see that a change to an HTML file triggers the restart...

```
web_1      | /src/templates/_nav.html changed, reloading.
web_1      | Watching for file changes with StatReloader
web_1      | Performing system checks...
web_1      | 
web_1      | System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
web_1      | April 27, 2021 - 14:16:17
web_1      | Django version 3.2, using settings 'demo.settings'
web_1      | Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
web_1      | Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

Comment: BTW, that is a feature I would like to have :D

Comment: Have a look [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/api/#django.template.loaders.cached.Loader)

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug in Django having a [ticket #32744](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/32744) and it is fixed in version 3.2.4 ([release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/releases/3.2.4/)). The simplest solution would hence be to upgrade Django to a newer version:

```
python -m pip install -U Django
```

Or if you cannot do that for some reason then you need to fix the indirect cause of the problem, which is that newer Django projects use `pathlib.Path` whereas older projects used strings to indicate the template directory, etc. hence a solution would be to upgrade / update your settings to use `pathlib.Path`. In general updating the below settings should help you (you might need to change others too where you use `BASE_DIR`):

```
from pathlib import Path


BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# showing only relevant parts of the TEMPLATES setting
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates'] # I don't show the other keys, but don't remove them!
    },
]
```